# How do I install Python in my operating system properly

Tags: python, opencv

While I install python in windows 10 operation System every single time I get error for importing opencv.

Comment: Python does not come with OpenCV. You're to install it after installing python. See https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the OpenCV package and reinstalling Python. Also you might need to downgrade your Python version.